# HTML table: Expand rowspan and colspan values as entries to validate table using XSLt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I hope you have a beautiful day.
I'm creating an XSLT code to validate html table is properly structured or not. To validate the table, first I have to expand rowspan and colspan values as each entries "td" in respective rows. Finally, I will check each rows "td" count against "cols" count.

My HTML table is

```
<table-wrap id="tbl1" position="float">
            <label>Table 1</label>
            <caption>
                <p></p>
            </caption>
            <alternatives>
                <graphic xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
                <table frame="hsides">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col align="left"/>
                        <col align="left"/>
                        <col align="left"/>
                        <col align="left"/>
                        <col align="left"/>
                        <col align="left"/>
                        <col align="left"/>
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2" align="left">1</th>
                            <th colspan="5" align="center">2</th>
                            <th rowspan="2" align="center">3</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="center">4</th>
                            <th align="center">5</th>
                            <th align="center">6</th>
                            <th align="center">7</th>
                            <th align="center">8</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td rowspan="2">10</td>
                            <td>11</td>
                            <td>12</td>
                            <td>13</td>
                            <td>14</td>
                            <td rowspan="2">15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>16</td>
                            <td>17</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                            <td>19</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td colspan="2">22</td>
                            <td rowspan="2">23</td>
                            <td colspan="2">24</td>
                            <td>25</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>26</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                            <td>28</td>
                            <td>29</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>31</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2">32</td>
                            <td colspan="2">33</td>
                            <td>34</td>
                            <td colspan="2">35</td>
                            <td rowspan="2">36</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2">37</td>
                            <td>38</td>
                            <td>39</td>
                            <td>40</td>
                            <td>41</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </alternatives>
        </table-wrap>
```

my XSLT code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="table">
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="thead"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tbody"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="thead">
  <thead>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tr"/>
  </thead>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody">
  <tbody>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tr"/>
  </tbody>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr">
  <xsl:variable name="current-row" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="td[@rowspan > 1]">
    <xsl:variable name="current-col" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rowspan-value" select="@rowspan"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $rowspan-value">
      <xsl:variable name="next-row" select="$current-row + (position() - 1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="col-value" select="."/>
      <xsl:variable name="colspan-value" select="@colspan"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to $colspan-value">
        <xsl:variable name="col-position" select="$current-col + (position() - 1)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="row-tag" select="count(../preceding-sibling::tr[position() lt $next-row]) + 1"/>
        <xsl:variable name="col-tag" select="count(./td[position() lt $col-position]) + 1"/>
        <xsl:element name="td">
          <xsl:value-of select="$col-value"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:for-each select="td[@colspan > 1]">
    <xsl:variable name="current-col" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="colspan-value" select="@colspan"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $colspan-value">
      <xsl:variable name="col-position" select="$current-col + (position() - 1)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="col-value" select="."/>
      <xsl:variable name="row-tag" select="count(../preceding-sibling::tr) + 1"/>
      <xsl:variable name="col-tag" select="count(./td[position() lt $col-position] + 1)"/>
            <xsl:element name="td">
        <xsl:value-of select="$col-value"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:for-each select="td">
    <xsl:if test="not(@rowspan) and not(@colspan)">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want the output like
`<th rowspan="2" align="left">1</th>` and
`<th rowspan="2" align="center">3</th>` as
`<th align="left">1< /th>` and
`<th align="center">3</th>` in first and second rows of `<tr>`

Similarly,
`<td colspan="2">22</td>` as `<td>22</td><td>22</td>` two `td` tags based on value mentioned in it

Expected output:

```
<table-wrap id="tbl1" position="float">
            <label>Table 1</label>
            <caption>
                <p></p>
            </caption>
            <alternatives>
                <graphic xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
                <table frame="hsides">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col/>
                        <col/>
                        <col/>
                        <col/>
                        <col/>
                        <col/>
                        <col/>
                    </colgroup>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>2</th>
                            <th>2</th>
                            <th>2</th>
                            <th>2</th>
                            <th>2</th>
                            <th>3</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>4</th>
                            <th>5</th>
                            <th>6</th>
                            <th>7</th>
                            <th>8</th>
                            <th>3</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>11</td>
                            <td>12</td>
                            <td>13</td>
                            <td>14</td>
                            <td>15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>16</td>
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>17</td>
                            <td>18</td>
                            <td>19</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>15</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>24</td>
                            <td>24</td>
                            <td>25</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>26</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>28</td>
                            <td>29</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>31</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>32</td>
                            <td>33</td>
                            <td>33</td>
                            <td>34</td>
                            <td>35</td>
                            <td>35</td>
                            <td>36</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>32</td>
                            <td>38</td>
                            <td>39</td>
                            <td>40</td>
                            <td>41</td>
                            <td>36</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>37</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </alternatives>
        </table-wrap>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the final updated version of my XSLT code will produce the expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table-validation>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//table"/>
        </table-validation>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:variable name="normalizedTable">
            <table name="normalizedTable">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="thead"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tbody"/>
            </table>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:call-template name="generate-table">
            <xsl:with-param name="normalizedTable" select="$normalizedTable"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="thead">
        <thead>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tr"/>
        </thead>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tbody">
        <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tr"/>
        </tbody>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="generate-columns">
        <xsl:param name="column-index"/>
        <xsl:param name="col-span"/>
        <xsl:if test="$col-span > 0">
            <td>C</td>
            <xsl:call-template name="generate-columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="column-index" select="$column-index + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="col-span" select="$col-span - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr" name="second">

        <xsl:variable name="currentPosition" select="count(preceding-sibling::tr)+1"/>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="td[1]|th[1]">
                <xsl:for-each select="../preceding-sibling::tr/td/@rowspan|../preceding-sibling::tr/th/@rowspan">
                    <xsl:variable name="previousRowspan">
                        <xsl:value-of select="number(.) "/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="rowspanValue">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$previousRowspan - 1"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="previousPosition">
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(../../preceding-sibling::tr)+1"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$previousRowspan and $rowspanValue &gt;= $currentPosition - $previousPosition">
                            <td>R</td>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="td|th">
                <td>D</td>
                <xsl:call-template name="generate-columns">
                    <xsl:with-param name="column-index" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="col-span" select="@colspan - 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="generate-table">
        <xsl:param name="normalizedTable"/>

        <xsl:variable name="cols" select="count(colgroup/col)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="rows" select="count($normalizedTable//tr)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="total-td" select="count($normalizedTable//td|$normalizedTable//td)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="expected-total-td" select="$rows * $cols"/>

        <table label="{ancestor::table-wrap/label}">
            <xsl:attribute name="total-rows" select="$rows"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="cols" select="$cols"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="expected-total-td" select="$expected-total-td"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="total-td" select="$total-td"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="is-valid" select="$expected-total-td = $total-td"/>

            <thead>
                <xsl:for-each select="$normalizedTable//thead/tr">
                    <xsl:variable name="tdCount" select="count(td)"/>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:attribute name="cols" select="$cols"/>
                        <xsl:attribute name="tdCount" select="$tdCount"/>
                        <xsl:attribute name="is-valid" select="$tdCount = $cols"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="td"/>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="$normalizedTable//tbody/tr">
                    <xsl:variable name="tdCount" select="count(td)"/>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:attribute name="cols" select="$cols"/>
                        <xsl:attribute name="tdCount" select="$tdCount"/>
                        <xsl:attribute name="is-valid" select="$tdCount = $cols"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="td"/>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this way easy to identify the mismatch using the attribute "is-valid="true|false"".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To give you a start using **xslt 2.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  >
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:variable name="colcount" select=" count(colgroup/col)"/>
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="colcount" select="$colcount" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="thead|tbody">
    <xsl:param name="colcount"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="entryCheck" as="element()*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tr"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="entryCountCheck"      select="count($entryCheck)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="entryCountShouldBe"   select="$colcount * count(tr)"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="entryCountShouldBe"  select="$entryCountShouldBe"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="entryCountCheck"     select="$entryCountCheck"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="isVald"              select="$entryCountShouldBe=$entryCountCheck"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$entryCheck"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="tr">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:variable name="current-col-name" select="local-name()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="current-col-pos"  select="position()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="col-value"        select="text()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="rowspan-value"    select="if(@rowspan) then @rowspan else 1"/>
      <xsl:variable name="colspan-value"    select="if(@colspan) then @colspan else 1"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to $rowspan-value">
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $colspan-value">
          <xsl:element name="{$current-col-name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$col-value"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will give you this result:

```
<table-wrap id="tbl1" position="float">
   <label>Table 1</label>
   <caption>
      <p/>
   </caption>
   <alternatives>
      <graphic xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
      <table xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <colgroup>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
            <col align="left"/>
         </colgroup>
         <thead entryCountShouldBe="14" entryCountCheck="14" isVald="true">
            <th>1</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody entryCountShouldBe="42" entryCountCheck="43" isVald="false">
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>34</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>41</td>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </alternatives>
</table-wrap>
```

Comment: Thansk @Siebe for answering, I have included the expected output for better understanding

Comment: Your code is efficacious for inspecting whether the total count of entries is mismatched with the expected entries count. 
However, I need to reproduce an output XML by expanding rowspan and colspan values in respective rows so that validation can be possible to identify the exact problematic row.

Comment: That is a lot more challenging.
To deal with the @rowspan I think you will need a recursive template.
I keep you posted

Comment: Yes, no one found a solution for this validation. I'm trying to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a piece of code that can automatically expand the number of rows and columns in tables, which can be beneficial to anyone who is searching for this type of code.

This XSLT code defines a set of templates for transforming an input XML document with a table structure. The transformed output is also a table but with some additional modifications.

The first template matches the top-level "table" element and creates a new "table" element in the output. It then applies templates to the "thead" and "tbody" child elements.

The second and third templates match the "thead" and "tbody" elements respectively, and create new "thead" and "tbody" elements in the output. They both apply templates to the "tr" child elements.

The fourth template is named "generate-columns" and takes two parameters, "column-index" and "col-span". It generates a set of "td" elements with the content "C" and recursively calls itself with the "col-span" parameter decremented by 1, until "col-span" is 0.

The fifth template matches the "tr" element and is named "second". It creates a new "tr" element in the output and processes the child "td" elements. For each "td" element, it creates a new "td" element in the output with the content "D", and then calls the "generate-columns" template with the "col-span" parameter taken from the "colspan" attribute of the "td" element. Additionally, it checks if the "td" element has a "rowspan" attribute and, if so, it creates additional "td" elements with the content "R" for the remaining rows in the span.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="table">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="thead"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tbody"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="thead">
    <thead>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tr"/>
    </thead>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tbody">
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tr"/>
    </tbody>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="generate-columns">
        <xsl:param name="column-index"/>
        <xsl:param name="col-span"/>
        <xsl:if test="$col-span > 0">
            <td>
                C
            </td>
            <xsl:call-template name="generate-columns">
                <xsl:with-param name="column-index" select="$column-index + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="col-span" select="$col-span - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr" name="second">
        
        <xsl:variable name="currentPosition" select="count(preceding-sibling::tr)+1"/>
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="td[1]">
                <xsl:for-each select="../preceding-sibling::tr/td/@rowspan">
                    <xsl:variable name="previousRowspan">
                        <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="rowspanValue">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$previousRowspan - 1"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="previousPosition">
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(../../preceding-sibling::tr)+1"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:message>a<xsl:value-of select="$currentPosition"/>b<xsl:value-of select="$previousPosition"/>c<xsl:value-of select="$previousRowspan"/>d<xsl:value-of select="$rowspanValue"/>
                    </xsl:message>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$previousRowspan and $rowspanValue &gt;= $currentPosition - $previousPosition">
                            <td>R</td>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                 </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="td">
                <td>
            D
        </td>
        <xsl:call-template name="generate-columns">
            <xsl:with-param name="column-index" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="col-span" select="@colspan - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```